# Linking day-night-cycle to a clock

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title suggests, I am trying to link my daynightcycle to my clock. Currently the cycle works, but its not matched correctly with my clock. And rather than trying to find the perfect rotationspeed value I'd much rather have it automated so I can also skip time etc and have the cycle match that. Currently I have this:

```cs
    private const float DAY_IN_SECONDS = 10f;
    private float day;

    public GameObject DayNightCycle;
    public GameObject UI;
    public GameObject Clock;
    private Transform hourHand;
    private Transform minuteHand;

    void Awake()
    {
        hourHand = Clock.transform.Find("hourHand");
        minuteHand = Clock.transform.Find("minuteHand");
    }

    private void UpdateClock()
    {
        day += Time.deltaTime / DAY_IN_SECONDS;
        // normalize day to always give value between 0 and 1.
        float dayNormalized = day % 1f;

        float dayRotation = 360f;
        hourHand.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -dayNormalized * dayRotation);

        float dayHours = 12f;
        minuteHand.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -dayNormalized * dayRotation * dayHours);

        DayNightCycle.transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.back, **SMTH HERE**);
        DayNightCycle.transform.LookAt(Vector3.zero);
    }
```

As I have it now, the clock works just fine, and rotates 2x per day (As I want it to) What I want is for the DayNightCycle to rotate based on the time of day. How would I go about this? I've tried quite a few things, even using DayNightCycle.transform.EulerAngles but that wouldnt make it rotate.

Comment: you need to supply the rotation angle in `**SMTH HERE**` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Yes I know, but my question is what do I put there. I've tried multiple things but Idk what the formula/value is I should be having there.

Comment: Ok, I was not understanding the problem. I think I do now. Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
float dayInseconds = dayHours * 60 * 60; // day duration to seconds. 43200 sec for 12 h in your example
```

Then your angle is:

```
float angle = (360 * day) / dayInseconds;
```

For the case of a half of your day (6h = 21600 sec) you achieve (360 * 21600)/(12 * 60 * 60) = 180º

Comment: Hey @rustyBucketBay thanks for the response, I ended up figuring it out and reworked it to go with eulerAngles. Ended up doing it like this: 

```DayNightCycle.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3((-dayNormalized * dayRotation), 90, 0);```

Your way probably also works, but ended up going with this as I figured it out myself and am somewhat happy/proud with it)

Comment: nice! glad you found out ;)